# How can match an object to a query with Javascript/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http

I am trying to find a way to return the URL of a query based on whether or not the data given was found within that query output. This is what I am doing and what I am trying to do:

```
var homes = ["home1","home2","home3"]; // Given
var addresses = [query1,query2];       //Given only as URLs

for(var i = 0; i < homes.length; i++){

    /*Find the matching query to JSON object where home object is stored*/
    var theRightAddress = find(homes[i],addresses);

    /*Make sure the variable is found*/
    console.log(theRightAddress);

}
```

In the data in query1 and query2 should appear as objects like:

```
[home1, home7, home32] /* for query1 */

[home2, home3, home102] /* for query2 */
```

BUT, I am only given the urls to these queries. So, Query1 may appear something like the link https://foo/foo/foo/query1 and Query2 like https://foo/foo/foo/query2.

So, addresses is actually:

```
var addresses = ["https://foo/foo/foo/query1","https://foo/foo/foo/query1"];
```

I am simply trying to match the addresses with the homes (that are given). I have tried AngularJS HTTP GET requests, but I can't seem to return any of the results since you need to use promises. All I am really looking for is a way to implement find() such that it returns the correct URL and sets theRightAddress.

Ex.) find("home1",addresses) should return:

```
https://foo/foo/foo/query1
```

Ex.) find("home2",addresses) should return:

```
https://foo/foo/foo/query2
```

Ex.) find("home3",addresses) should return:

```
https://foo/foo/foo/query2
```

Comment: If the queries still have to be made when you do the search, then this will inevitably involve asynchronous code, so either promises or old-fashioned callbacks. But in either case you cannot get the result in a synchronous call and return syntax.

Comment: Even if you could find a magic function that does what you ask, it doesn't seem like you can reliably make this work. Since REST is a stateless pattern, the query might match the data, but only for the time being. As soon as the data changes, even slightly, you're URLs would no longer match up with the data returned.

Comment: I did end up finding something that worked. However, it was pretty frustrating process. :(